# button is not aligned with the header

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a header with a logo a dropdown menu and a search bar the problem is that dropdown button it's down and I want it to up.
I have this way:
[image]

But I want something like this where button is align with the logo and search bar: 
[image]

I have tried a lot of things like call the class of button in css and put margin-button with a lot of pxls but its work, any suggestion?
This is my code HTML where I have the button:

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse js-navbar-collapse">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <div class="cd-dropdown-wrapper">
      <button type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle cd-dropdown-trigger">Categorias</button>
    </div>
  </ul>
</div>
```

This is my css code:

```
.btn-default {
  margin-bottom: 350px;
  background: #25727D;
  border-color: #25727D;
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 50px;
}
```

```css
.navbar-custom {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  background-color: #283133;
}

.navbar-custom .navbar-nav>li>a {
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

.navbar-header {
  max-height: 60px;
}

.form-group {
  margin: auto;
}

.navbar-nav {
  margin-left: 200px;
}

.navbar-left {
  margin-left: 30px;
}

.navbar-form {
  margin-left: 550px;
  margin-bottom: 170px;
  position: absolute;
}

.btn:hover,
.btn:focus,
.btn:active,
.btn.active,
.btn:active:focus,
.btn {
  background: #25727D;
  border-color: #25727D;
}

.btn-default {
  margin-bottom: 350px;
  background: #25727D;
  border-color: #25727D;
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 50px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-pt">

<head>
  <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->

  <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
  <!-- <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> -->
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
  <script src="assets/js/jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>

  <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
  <script src="assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link href="assets/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/reset.css">
  <!-- CSS reset -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/co.css">
  <!-- Resource style -->

  <script src="assets/js/main.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/js/jquery.menu-aim.js"></script>
  <!-- menu aim -->
  <script src="assets/js/modernizr.js"></script>
  <!-- Modernizr -->




</head>

<body>

  <header>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-custom" role="navigation">
      <div class="container">
        <a class="navbar-left" href="#"><img src="assets/img/logo-01.png" style="max-width:70px" /></a>
        <div class="navbar-header navbar-left">


          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse js-navbar-collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
              <div class="cd-dropdown-wrapper">
                <button type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle cd-dropdown-trigger">Categorias</button>




                <form class="navbar-form navbar-left">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Pesquisar Produto">
                  </div>
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">
              <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i>
             </button>
                </form>
              </div>
          </div>
        </div>


    </nav>

  </header>
```

Comment: Is there are reason for you using absolute positioning? Because that is the main problem that I see here and the overuse of margins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using absolute positioning.
**You could use the `top` property of css to place it at the top of the page.**

Instead of using margins,

```
margin-bottom: 350px;
```

use

```
top:5px; /*adjust to your preference*/
```

**There are easier ways of creating headers.**

Here's a jsFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/160211/

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can try and make your HTML like this and see if it works! Maybe it was just a positioning problem. Moving the button to where the navbar is supposed to be should do it.

```
<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<!-- <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> -->
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
<script src="assets/js/jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>

<!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
<script src="assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="assets/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/reset.css">
<!-- CSS reset -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/co.css">
<!-- Resource style -->

<script src="assets/js/main.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/jquery.menu-aim.js"></script>
<!-- menu aim -->
<script src="assets/js/modernizr.js"></script>
<!-- Modernizr -->
```

```
<header>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-custom" role="navigation">
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse js-navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <div class="cd-dropdown-wrapper">

          <button type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle cd-dropdown-trigger">Categorias</button>

        </div>
      </ul>

      <div class="container">
        <a class="navbar-left" href="#"><img src="assets/img/logo-01.png" style="max-width:70px"/></a>
        <div class="navbar-header navbar-left">
          <form class="navbar-form navbar-left">
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Pesquisar Produto">
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">
                            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i>
                        </button>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
</header>
```